# How do I iterate through all the id's?

Tags: javascript

Check out the api --> https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/10

Everytime when the user clicks on a specific joke, it will be added to the favorite list.

To keep the code concise I will only show the function itself:

```js
 (function() {
 "use strict";
  
 const getJokesButton = document.getElementById('getData');
 getJokesButton.addEventListener('click', getData);

 loadLocalStorage();

 function loadLocalStorage() {
  let storage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favoList')) || [];
  let listOfFavorites = document.getElementById("favorites");
  let emptyArray = '';
  if(storage.length > 0) {
   for(let i = 0; i < storage.length; i++) {
    let idNumberJoke = storage[i].id;
    emptyArray += 
    `<li><input type="checkbox" id='${idNumberJoke}'/> User title: ${storage[i].joke}</li>`;
    listOfFavorites.innerHTML = emptyArray;
   }
  } else {
   return false;
  }
 }
 
 // fetch data from api
 function getData() {
  let listOfJokes = document.getElementById("list-of-jokes"); 

  fetch('https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/10')
  .then(function(res) {
   return res.json();
  }).then(function(data) { 
   // variable is undefined because it is not initialized. Therefore at some empty single quotes
   let result = '';
   console.log(data.value);
   data.value.forEach((joke) => {
    result +=
    `<li><input type="checkbox" class='inputCheckbox' id='${joke.id}'/> User title :  ${joke.joke}</li>`;
    listOfJokes.innerHTML = result;
   });
   bindCheckbox();
  }).catch(function(err) {
   console.log(err);
  });
 }

 function clickedButton() {
  getJokesButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  getJokesButton.classList.add('opacity');
 }

 function bindCheckbox() {
  let inputCheckbox = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
  let elems = document.getElementById('list-of-jokes').childNodes;
  let favoriteList = document.getElementById('favorites');
  let fav = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favoList'))|| [];

  if(elems.length > 0) { 
   inputCheckbox.forEach(function(element, index) {
    inputCheckbox[index].addEventListener('change', function() {
     let joke = this;
     if(joke.checked && joke.parentNode.parentNode.id === 'list-of-jokes') { 
        joke.checked = false;
        favoriteList.appendChild(joke.parentNode);
        addFavorite(joke.id, joke.parentNode.innerText, fav);
     } 
     if(joke.checked && joke.parentNode.parentNode.id === 'favorites') {
        joke.checked = false;
        removeFavorite(joke, index);
     }
    });
   });
  }
  clickedButton();
 }

 function removeFavorite(favorite, index) {
  let favoriteCheckBox = favorite;
  let i = index;

  // convert iterable object to an array, otherwise splice method would give an error.
  let favoriteListItem = Array.from(favoriteCheckBox.parentNode); 
  favoriteListItem.splice(i, 1);
  document.getElementById('list-of-jokes').appendChild(favorite.parentNode);
  localStorage.setItem('favoList', JSON.stringify(favoriteListItem));
 }

 // store favorites in localStorage
 function addFavorite(jokeId, jokeText, fav) {
  let norrisJoke = {
   id: jokeId,
   joke: jokeText
  };
  let favorites = fav;

  for (let i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) {
   if(favorites[i].id !== norrisJoke.id) {
    favorites.push(norrisJoke);
   }
  }
  // favorites[i].id !== norrisJoke.id
  
  // always get the object before the push method and pass it into stringify
  localStorage.setItem('favoList', JSON.stringify(favorites));
 } 
   
   // function which will randomly add one joke to favorite list every 5 seconds
   // function need a button which allows you to turn on and off this auto add function
})();
```

```html
<div class="inner-body">
  <button id="getData">GET Jokes</button>

  <div class='inner-block'>
   <h2>Chuck Norris Jokes</h2>

   <ul class='unordered-list' id="list-of-jokes">
   </ul>
  </div>

  <div class='inner-block'>
   <h2>Favorites</h2>
   <ul class='unordered-list' id="favorites">
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The keys and values would not be pushed into localStorage, the only thing I see is an empty [] in localStorage. The norrisJoke object literal will be dynamically changed. So how could I make this function works?

Too complex, but click on the link below and scroll down to the bottom:

https://codepen.io/chichichi/pen/Gyzzvb

Comment: You need to add at least enough code for us to run what you have. It's also, not great to start off a question with "Go read about what I am working with over here.". You should include all relevant information in the question.

Comment: Unless your `favoList` does not contain at least one element to begin with nothing will happen in the for loop because `favorites.length == 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run through an empty list here

```
for (let i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) {
    if(favorites[i].id !== norrisJoke.id) {
        favorites.push(norrisJoke);
    }
}
```

This means that nothing will ever be pushed. You can reduce your list to an array of `id`, then check if the joke exists in the list.

```
const favIds = favorites.reduce((sum, element) => { 
        return sum.concat(element.id); 
    }, 
[]);
```

Now you can check if the joke doesn't exists in favorites

```
if(!favIds.includes(jokeId)){
    favorites.push(norrisJoke);
}
```

Comment: Thank you have taught me the reduce function which I hadn't seen before :)

Comment: I'd say Fabian solution is cleaner though

Comment: His basically says. Filter out all the jokes where `joke.id` is equal to `norrisJoke.id`. This means that if the `joke` exists in the `favorites`, then it is removed. Now we know for sure that the `joke` doesn't exist in the `favorites`, so we just add the `norrisJoke` using `concat`

Answer (score 1):

```
let favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favoList'))|| {};

favorites[norrisJoke.id] =norrisJoke.joke
```

Why don't you use a map in place of an array?

Also as  @fl9 points out your for loop will never start off! because `favorites.length` is 0 to begin with

> But I want to check duplicates before the joke will be pushed into favorite list

By definition a hash will not allow duplicate entries, so no need to worry about duplications

Run `localStorage.getItem('favoList')` in the console of [this](https://jsfiddle.net/saffrons/e131jqqa/) fiddle :

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    const getJokesButton = document.getElementById('getData');
    getJokesButton.addEventListener('click', getData);

    loadLocalStorage();

    function loadLocalStorage() {
        let storage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favoList')) || [];
        let listOfFavorites = document.getElementById("favorites");
        let emptyArray = '';
        if(storage.length > 0) {
            for(let i = 0; i < storage.length; i++) {
                let idNumberJoke = storage[i].id;
                emptyArray += 
                `<li><input type="checkbox" id='${idNumberJoke}'/> User title: ${storage[i].joke}</li>`;
                listOfFavorites.innerHTML = emptyArray;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // fetch data from api
    function getData() {
        let listOfJokes = document.getElementById("list-of-jokes"); 

        fetch('https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/10')
        .then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
        }).then(function(data) { 
            // variable is undefined because it is not initialized. Therefore at some empty single quotes
            let result = '';
            console.log(data.value);
            data.value.forEach((joke) => {
                result +=
                `<li><input type="checkbox" class='inputCheckbox' id='${joke.id}'/> User title :  ${joke.joke}</li>`;
                listOfJokes.innerHTML = result;
            });
            bindCheckbox();
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    function clickedButton() {
        getJokesButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        getJokesButton.classList.add('opacity');
    }

    function bindCheckbox() {
        let inputCheckbox = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
        let elems = document.getElementById('list-of-jokes').childNodes;
        let favoriteList = document.getElementById('favorites');
        let fav = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favoList'))|| [];

        if(elems.length > 0) {  
            inputCheckbox.forEach(function(element, index) {
                inputCheckbox[index].addEventListener('change', function() {
                    let joke = this;
                    if(joke.checked && joke.parentNode.parentNode.id === 'list-of-jokes') { 
                       joke.checked = false;
                       favoriteList.appendChild(joke.parentNode);
                       addFavorite(joke.id, joke.parentNode.innerText, fav);
                    } 
                    if(joke.checked && joke.parentNode.parentNode.id === 'favorites') {
                       joke.checked = false;
                       removeFavorite(joke, index);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        clickedButton();
    }

    function removeFavorite(favorite, index) {
        let favoriteCheckBox = favorite;
        let i = index;

        // convert iterable object to an array, otherwise splice method would give an error.
        let favoriteListItem = Array.from(favoriteCheckBox.parentNode); 
        favoriteListItem.splice(i, 1);
        document.getElementById('list-of-jokes').appendChild(favorite.parentNode);
        localStorage.setItem('favoList', JSON.stringify(favoriteListItem));
    }

    // store favorites in localStorage
    function addFavorite(jokeId, jokeText, fav) {
        let norrisJoke = {
            id: jokeId,
            joke: jokeText
        };
        let favorites = fav;

        for (let i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) {
            if(favorites[i].id !== norrisJoke.id) {
                favorites.push(norrisJoke);
            }
        }
        // favorites[i].id !== norrisJoke.id

        // always get the object before the push method and pass it into stringify
        localStorage.setItem('favoList', JSON.stringify(favorites));
    }   

   // function which will randomly add one joke to favorite list every 5 seconds
   // function need a button which allows you to turn on and off this auto add function
})();
```

Comment: I was writing the exact same answer! Jokes have already a unique ID so there's absolutely no reason to do funky stuff using `for (array length bla)`

Comment: But I want to check duplicates before the joke will be pushed into favorite list.

Comment: Read Pavlo's answer, its explanatory of your conundrum. And my suggestion would be to use a hash in place of an array, it gets rid of your checks and looping code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the for loop, the first time it's executed favorites will be an empty array so it's length will be 0, so it will never enter the loop

Something like this should work:

```
favorites = favorites.filter(joke => joke.id !== norrisJoke.id).concat(norrisJoke);
```